# $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n b_n=\infty$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=b>0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let me settle down the definition of $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$ first. A real sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is said to diverge to infinity if $\forall M>0$, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $n\geq N\Rightarrow a_n>M$. Now I'd like to prove a property concerning infinite limits in the above sense: if $a_n\to\infty$ and $b_n\to b>0$, then  $a_n b_n\to\infty$.

My proof proceeded with the definition of infinite limits. First write
$$a_n b_n=a_n(b_n-b)+a_n b.\tag{*}$$
Then pick $N_b\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $n\geq N_b\Rightarrow|b_n-b|<b$ and choose $N_a\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $n\geq N_a\Rightarrow a_n>\frac{M}{b}$. Now let $N$ be the greater of $N_a$ and $N_b$. If $n\geq N$, then I only have $a_n b_n>0$ in view of (*). What should I do in order to get $a_n b_n>M$ instead? Thank you.

Comment: Since $b_n\to b$, you have $b_n>b-\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon>0$ and $n$ sufficiently large. Now just take $a_n$ large enough so that $a_n(b-\varepsilon)>M$ and it follows that $a_nb_n>M$.

Comment: @Clayton Thank you, my friend, but I don't particularly agree that $b_n>b-\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$ and $n$ sufficiently large. Please consider the sequence $b_n=1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ and take $b_{99}$ for example.

Comment: I don’t see a problem here. For any $\varepsilon>0$, you can take $N$ large enough so that $b_n>1-\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$.

Comment: In the example just offered, how do you make $b_{99}+\epsilon$ greater than $1$ for **ALL** $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: You misunderstand. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Now you want to take $N$ large enough so that $b_n>b-\varepsilon$. This is directly from the definition of the limit: $|b_n-b|<\varepsilon\Rightarrow b_n>b-\varepsilon$. (Note: I’m assuming $b>0$ as in the post).

Comment: @Clayton Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think ($*$) actually just confuses matters. Since $b_n\to b>0$, we can choose $N_b\in\Bbb{N}$ so that for all $n\geq N_b$, we have $|b_n-b|<\frac{b}{2}$, and thus $b_n>\frac{b}{2}$. Next, given $M>0$, choose an appropriate $N_a$. Then, for $n\geq \max(N_a,N_b)$, we have $a_nb_n>a_n\frac{b}{2}$. I leave it to you to continue from here.

Note that this proof reveals something about the problem statement. The hypothesis $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=b$ is unnecessarily strong (and this unnecessarily strong hypothesis led you to an "incorrect" approach). It was important for us that $b>0$, but we don't really care about what the limiting value of $\{b_n\}$ is. We don't even need this limit to exist. All we need is for $\{b_n\}$ to "eventually be positive and stay away from $0$". More explicitly, the following is true:

> If $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are sequences such that
>
> - $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$
> - there is an $N_0\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $\inf\limits_{n\geq N_0}b_n >0$,
>
> then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_nb_n=\infty$.